# Keep getting `NoneType` errors when parsing logs with regex

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, logparser

I have an example of what two of the logs look like below.  I'm trying to get out the ip, date_time, method, this part (`/071300/242153 HTTP/1.1"`), response code (just `404`/`200` part), and the rest in one group:

`66.249.69.97 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000] "GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`

and

`71.19.157.174 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"`

My function looks like:

```
def parse_logs(logs):
  log_list = []
  for log in logs:
    p = re.compile(r'''(?P<ip_addr>\d+(\.\d+){3}) - - \[(?P<date_time>.+?)\] (?P<http_method>\".+?\") (?P<return_code>\d+) \d+ "-" (?P<client>\".+?\")''')

    m = p.search(log)

    log_list.append([m.group('ip_addr'), m.group('date_time'), m.group('http_method'), m.group('return_code'), m.group('client')])

rdd_prepped = parse_logs(rdd.take(5))
```

When I pass a list of these logs to the function and run it, I keep getting the error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'collect'`.

When I put a `print(m.group('ip'))` line under `m = p.search(log)`, I get the error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Why do I keep getting NoneTypes?  I'm using Python2.7 btw.

Comment: Your regex is matching anything and `p.search` is returning `None` from the docs https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search

Comment: Edit: Sorry, ignore this comment, I hadn't copied and pasted the regex into the tool correctly.

Comment: It looks like your regex isn't matching one or more of the lines in your log files, making `p.search` return `None`. Have you tried printing out the ones that don't match? That might give you a hint as to what's wrong.

Comment: @HarryCutts According to regex101.com, they all match.

Comment: OK, but there may be implementation details of your code that's not immediately obvious as you copy and paste. (For example, there might be a trailing empty line in the file that's not matching.) Adding `if m is None: print log` after the `p.search` call might highlight them.

Comment: @HarryCutts It prints nothing :/ .....although so does `if m: print(log)`

Comment: Edit: actually it `if not m: print(log)` did print the log.  It works in regex101.com though.  No trailing spaces or anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201748/discussion-between-harry-cutts-and-sam-dillard).

Comment: When first posted, the regex pattern was split on two lines with a '\' at the end of the first line.  But the pattern is in triple quotes. So the regex actually required a '\n' in the log.  So the pattern did not match.  The pattern has been edited so it is on one line, and it appears to work.

Comment: @RootTwo this was the answer. Feel free to write up and I'll check it off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this was first posted, the regex looked like this:

```
p = re.compile(r'''(?P<ip>\d+(\.\d+){3}) - - \[(?P<date_time>.+?)\] (?P<method>\".+?\") \
    (?P<response_code>\d+) \d+ "-" (?P<client>\".+?\")''')
```

Note the line continuation character (a '\') at the end of the first line.  But the pattern is also in triple quotes.  So the pattern includes the text `'\\n     '` (slash + newline + indent).  As a result, the pattern wouldn't match.

Rewrite the pattern on a single line and it should work:

```
p = re.compile(r'''(?P<ip>\d+(\.\d+){3}) - - \[(?P<date_time>.+?)\] (?P<method>\".+?\") (?P<response_code>\d+) \d+ "-" (?P<client>\".+?\")''')
```

For complicated regular expressions, I like to use verbose mode:

```
regex = re.compile("""
    (?P<ip>\d+(?:\.\d+){3})     # four, dot-separated sets of digits
    .*?                         # skip ahead
    \[(?P<date_time>.*?)\]      # date time is everything between '[ ]'
    .*?                         # skip 
    "(?P<method>.*?)"           # method is everything between quotes
    .*?                         # skip 
    (?P<response_code>\d+)      # multiple digits
    .*?                         # skip
    "-"                         # don't care
    .*?                         #
    "(?P<client>.*?)"           # client is everything between quotes
    """, re.VERBOSE)
```

A few more things:

If you expect the regex to match (almost) every line in the log, then you should print/log any lines that don't match.  That helps catch errors in your regex, or when someone changes the log format without telling you.

Move the re.compile step out of the loop.

`MatchObject.group()` can take multiple arguments and returns a tuple of the listed groups.

```
def parse_logs(logs):
  log_list = []

  p = re.compile(...whichever regex style you like...)

  for log in logs:

    m = p.search(log)

    if m:
      log_list.append(m.group('ip_addr', 'date_time', 'http_method, 
                              'return_code', 'client'))
    else:
        print(log)

rdd_prepped = parse_logs(rdd.take(5))
```